# Pings are dropped when pinging a specific KVM guest

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization

I had a seriously latency when using SSH to Server1 and noticed when I ping Server1 that a lot of packets are dropped.  When I go to Server1 and enter ifconfig I do not see any errors or dropped packets.  Server1 is a guest in a KVM system.  I tried creating another network interface using the virtio driver.  The first interface used E1000.  I set a different IP on the second interface, but I see in my ARP cache that they both resolve to same MAC.

Here is interface config in KVM:

```
  `interface type='bridge'

  mac address='52:54:00:43:00:95'/

  source bridge='br0'/

  model type='e1000'/

  address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/

  /interface>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if other KVM guests have unique MAC address
Maybe you have two VMs with same MACs.

Comment: Yes, that was it!